# How do I make it so that I don't have to #import <CoreData/CoreData.h> in all my classes?

Tags: ios, core-data

If you create a new project with Xcode and tell it to create a CoreData template when you're creating the project you don't need to

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

in the classes that use ManagedObjects.

I've added a Core Data store to a pre-existing project that didn't start out with a CoreData template and find that I have to #import  in all my classes.

Anyway to get around this?

Comment: Ugh, why do you want to do this? You're hiding dependencies and making your source more brittle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` to the [prefix header](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/800-Reducing_Build_Times/bs_speed_up_build.html) used in your project (e.g. right after `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`). You can find the prefix header in Xcode’s project tree under Other Sources, and it should be named *yourProject*_Prefix.pch.